# Logical conditional in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I want the name of every male director that has directed more than 20 movies and has cast in every single movie he has directed. If he has cast a movie, but hasn't directed it, that's okay and I still want his name; if he has directed any movie but hasn't cast in it, I don't want him anymore.

```
SELECT p.firstname, 
    p.lastname 
FROM person p 
WHERE p.gender = 'M' AND
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM filmparticipation fpd 
    WHERE p.personid = fpd.personid AND
        fpd.parttype = 'director' AND
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM filmparticipation c 
            WHERE c.personid = fpd.personid AND
                c.filmid = fpd.filmid AND
                c.parttype = 'cast'
        ) > 0
) >= 20;
```

This is just one of my multiple tries. As a side question, why doesn't it work? I make sure I'm checking the correct directed movie-id to the casted movie-id etc.

Comment: can you create a fiddle for us?  sqlfiddle.com

Comment: I don't see your table definitions anywhere? Or the version of PostgreSQL ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could look like this:

```
SELECT p.firstname, p.lastname 
FROM   person p
JOIN  (
   SELECT fd.personid
   FROM   filmparticipation fd
   LEFT   JOIN filmparticipation fc USING (personid, filmid)
   WHERE  fd.parttype = 'director'
   AND    fc.parttype = 'cast'
   GROUP  BY fd.personid
   HAVING count(*) > 20  -- 21+ movies directed (NULL not counted)
   AND    NOT bool_or(fc.personid IS NULL) -- no movie directed but not cast
   ) AS fp USING (personid)
WHERE  p.gender = 'M';
```

In the subquery I [`LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) all rows where the same person for the same film directed and casted - Where (s)he only directed the rest is filled with `NULL`. That's what a `LEFT JOIN` does. This assumes that the same person can only appear *once* in the same role in the same film (UNIQUE or PK constraint!).

Grouping by `personid` has to result in more than 20 rows and none of the casting `personid` can be `NULL`. `JOIN` to the person table and restrict to males and you are done.

There are many ways to solve it, *this* should be one of the fastest.